# Make Inline SVG With Nested Images Accessible

Tags: html, svg, accessibility, wai-aria

I have the following svg in a webpage. Besides the `title` and `desc` tags I have added, is there anything else I can do to make this svg more accessible? For instance, are there attributes, roles, etc. I can add to the `image` tags for visually impaired users?

```
<svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
   <rect id="SvgjsRect1008" width="206" height="420" x="0" y="0" fill="#80ff72"></rect>
   <rect id="SvgjsRect1010" width="206" height="420" x="246.5" y="0" fill="#80ff72"></rect>
   <rect id="SvgjsRect1011" width="40.5" height="420" x="206" y="0" fill="#7ee8fa"></rect>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1012" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/common/raft.svg" width="206" height="206" x="206" y="107"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1013" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/goat.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="0"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1014" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/apple.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="108"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1015" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/wolf.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="216"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1016" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/farmer.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="324"></image>
   <title>Animation</title>
   <desc>Displays the animation</desc>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can't you simply make your desc contain all the description of the svg? Ps: Not visually impaired, but I'm not sure how I would really perceive "Displays the animation" as an useful description if I were. In your position I would probably reiterate the rebus as text in here.

Comment: Use the `aria-` attributes and the `role`attribute. This article about [Accessible SVGs](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/) may be useful. Also chapter 17 Beyond the Visible from [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design ](https://www.amazon.com/Using-SVG-CSS3-HTML5-Graphics/dp/1491921978/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1538291556&sr=8-1&keywords=amelia+bellamy-royds&dpID=51TL4eoVm%252BL&preST=_SY291_BO1,204,203,200_QL40_&dpSrc=srch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clear 'title' and a descriptive 'desc' are essential for Screen reader users to understand what the image conveys. Genereic information like 'Animation', 'Displays Animation' etc. doesn't help visually impaired users. Make it clear and descriptive if possible.

SVG title and desc are not uniformly supported by screen readers. role="img" and aria-labelledby should be used in the SVG tag to include title and desc id to arrive at a more consistent accessible name for the image.

```
    <svg id="SvgjsSvg1001" width="100%" height="100%" role="img" aria-labelledby="titleid descid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs">
   <rect id="SvgjsRect1008" width="206" height="420" x="0" y="0" fill="#80ff72"></rect>
   <rect id="SvgjsRect1010" width="206" height="420" x="246.5" y="0" fill="#80ff72"></rect>
   <rect id="SvgjsRect1011" width="40.5" height="420" x="206" y="0" fill="#7ee8fa"></rect>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1012" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/common/raft.svg" width="206" height="206" x="206" y="107"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1013" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/goat.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="0"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1014" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/apple.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="108"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1015" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/wolf.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="216"></image>
   <image id="SvgjsImage1016" xlink:href="./assets/river-crossing/goat-apple-wolf/farmer.svg" width="98" height="98" x="0" y="324"></image>
   <title id="titleid">Clear title</title>
   <desc id="descid">Description of the image</desc>
</svg>
```